# How do I implement a Semantic Parser to evaluate on a dataset?

Tags: parsing, implementation, semantics, review

As part of my bachelor-thesis I want to evaluate two Semantic Parsers on one common Dataset.
The two parsers are namely:
TRANX by Yin and Neubig: https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.02720 and
Seq2Action by Chen et al.: https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.00773

As I am relatively new to the topic I'm pretty much starting from scratch.
I don't know how to implement the parsers on my computer in order to run them on the ATIS or GeoQuery dataset.

It would be great if there is someone here who can help me with this problem as I have really no clue yet on how to approach this whole situation.

Comment: You'll need to start by finding (or requesting, or reproducing) the code. For example, a quick internet search for "tranx" found me this github repository: https://github.com/pcyin/tranX which seems to belong to one of the authors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for searching the Tranx repo. The code of the other parser is in this repo: github.com/dongpobeyond/Seq2Act   What would be the next step to implement these programs so I can run them on my computer?

Comment: At least in the case of Tranx, there are detailed instructions in the README.md file. I presume you've already read the paper. I presume that there are instructions in the Seq2Act repository as well.

Comment: I guess the instructions included in Tranx repo are pretty clear. Will I be able to "ask" the parser a question or is there "just" the predefined evaluation metrics for me to see?

Comment: I don't know a lot about this field either, but it looks to me like the intent is for you to customise Tranx for your specific problem domain. Good luck with your project!